# Region of interest in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I am struggling with this:

In a render view in Paraview, is it possible to draw a square or rectangle around the region of interest and have this as a close up render view in another window then being displayed?

Hope the question makes sense otherwise please comment and I provide a sketch of desired behaviour.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! I think you have to use the clip tool, then cut away what you are not interested in, so to say. You can also save the window state, so that you do not have to re-do it on reruns.

Comment: @MPIchael thank you, yes this is something I could do. However I will require, that in the "overview" render view I have a rectangle or square which delineates the region of interest visually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part: try *Sources* of ParaView to mark your region of interest.

You can insert Cylinders or Boxes into your view, and modify (translate, rotate or scale) them using the Transform filter.

[image]

Comment: Great! Is this supported also in older versions of Paraview?

Comment: The oldest version on my system I can check is 5.0.1 which supports Sources.

Comment: Thank you @Dohn Joe. This works fine actually. (I think the oldest version I use is 5.3.0 and it has support for Sources)